# How to attach a event to a jQuery mobile page using on() and off()?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm trying to upgrade to lasted Jquery 1.7.1 (using JQM 1.1pre).

I used to be able to bind to a JQM page like this:

```
$('#mypage').live('pageshow', function() { /* do stuff */ })
```

Per Jquery 1.7.1 this would now have to be:

```
$('#mypage').on('pageshow', function() { /* do stuff */ })
```

Or if the page is dynamically inserted

```
$('body').on('pageshow', '#mypage', function() { /* do stuff */ })
```

**Questions:**
- Is this syntax correct for jquery 1.7+?
- I cannot get the events to fire at all in JQM using this. I have tried `$('div:jqmData(role="page")#mypage` but this also does not seem to work. What would be the correct syntax to attach some functionality to a specific JQM page only?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
Some meddling later it seems you can only call `on()` and `off()` on `$('div:jqmData(role="page")')`. Calling on a respective **#pageID** does not work. In a multipage layout binding like this will fire once per page, so if you have 10 pages in your multipage document, this:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').on('pageshow', function() {
   // do stuff
   });
```

will fire 10 times or once per page in a multipage document.

I guess this will be adressed by JQM before 1.1 will be released. In the meantime, I use this as a sort-of-workaround to make sure stuff is only attached once.

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').on('pageshow', function() {
   console.log("one");

   if ( $('.element').length > 0 && $('.element').jqmData('bound') != true) {       
     $('.element').jqmData('bound',true);
     $('.element').on('click', function() { /* button click handler */ });  
     }
   });
```

I'm checking for length so the code only runs if *.element* is on the respective page and whether it hasn't been bound already. You can also use this to `off()` *.element* on pagebeforehide. Just don't forget to reset `jqmData('bound')`, so on the next pageshow it can be re-bound.

Comment: Why do you need to use `.on()`? I would have thought `.live()` would still work great in jQuery 1.7.* :/

Comment: @ChrisKempen - It still works, but is oficially deprecated. Otherwise the syntax looks to be correct, but if using both on and off it's probably a good idea to seperate the function and just call it, like so : `$('body').on('pageshow', '#mypage', myfunction);` and try to listen on the closest possible element, and not always on document or body.

Comment: @ChrisKempen: live is depreciated from 1.7 onwards http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Interesting...I have a feeling I'll be upgrading my code soon too! :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use $.on() to bind to all pages, as well as specific pages. I've created a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/aAanV/

I've added a pageinit/pageshow handler for ALL pages (to show that pageinit fires once per page, and pageshow fires each time page is shown). I then create a pageinit handler for #page1 to bind a click event handler on a button.

Notice the syntax. $(*elements*).on('*events*', '***selector***', *handler*) vs $(*elements*).on('*events*', *handler*);

If you include the *selector*, then you are *delegating* the handler to all elements that match the selector. If you DON'T include the selector, then you are *binding* the handler 
directly to the *elements*.

```
$(function() {
    // setup init/show handler for ALL pages
    var selector = ':jqmData(role=page)';
    $('body')
        .on('pageinit', selector, function(e, data) {
            // initialize page
            var $page = $(this);
            alert('init ' + $page.attr('id'));
        })
        .on('pageshow', selector, function(e, data) {
            // showpage
            var $page = $(this);
            alert('show ' + $page.attr('id'));
        });
    // setup init handler for page1
    $('#page1').on('pageinit', function(e, data) {
        // setup handler
        var $page = $(this);
        $page.find('.colorchanger').click(function() {
            var $content = $page.find('.ui-content'),
                isBodyC = $content.hasClass('ui-body-c');
            $content
                .toggleClass('ui-body-c', !isBodyC)
                .toggleClass('ui-body-e', isBodyC);
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: yes you are correct, I can bind to specific pages as well. My problem was I was trying to bind an event to the first page being loaded/init. This also works - see here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3696, but you have to add bindings before Jquery Mobile is loaded. Anyway. Good answer. Thanks a lot