# jQuery mobile run on pagechange event to a specific page

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

I want to catch the event if a specific jQuery mobile page changes. For example, I used the code which I indicated below:

```js
$(document).on("pagechange", function () {
    alert("page changed");
});
```

But, how can I make this function run only for a specific page, for example: the page which has id="myPage"? I want to make it give alert only when myPage is changed.

(* I use multiple page structure in jquery mobile)

Comment: `$('#pageID').on("pagechange", function () { etc....`

Comment: someone answered it here just like what omar had commented.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9609212/562036

Answer (score 1):

I think you could register events on page instead of document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Page 1</p>
    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#pagetwo" >TWO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">ONE</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p>Page 2</p>
  <div data-role="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">TWO</a></li>
     <li><a href="#pageone" >ONE</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#pageone").on("pageshow", function() {
    alert("cambio a pagina 1");
});
$("#pagetwo").on("pageshow", function() {
    alert("cambio a pagina 2");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you prefer pagechange event, you could get the page URL:

```
$(document).on("pagechange", function(toPage) {
    alert(toPage.currentTarget.URL);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('pagechange', '#myPage', function (event) {
    alert("I alert only on #myPage");
});
```

Comment: $('#myPage').on('pagechange', ... -- doesn't work, because the pagechange event is fired on the pagecontainer, see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/pagechange-event-not-firing